# Is it possible to have an asynchronous controller constructor in Angular.js?

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, angular-promise

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/tVEEezHh4QUrZosBYfde?p=preview) is a minimal example of a controller constructor returning a `$q`-based promise. The promise does get executed, but its results are not reflected in the view. Is there any way to have the completion of the promise trigger a refresh?

---

```
$scope.property = 0;
return $q((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {$scope.property = 1; resolve();}, 5000);
});
```

Comment: It would work if you actually resolved the promise or simply used `$timeout`

Comment: I've made that change (see updated plunkr) and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `$q` doesn't trigger a digest until the resolved promise is consumed. This works as expected

```
return $q((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {$scope.property = 1; resolve();}, 5000);
}).then(angular.noop);
```

Ideally, you'd actually use the resolver, eg

```
$q(resolver => 
    setTimeout(() => resolve(1), 5000)
).then(p => $scope.property = p);
```

or even more simply, use the `$timeout` service

```
$timeout(() => $scope.property = 1, 5000);
```

or using the promise returned by `$timeout`

```
$timeout(() => 1, 5000).then(p => $scope.property = p)
```